# How to open a file with epiceditor?

Tags: javascript, epiceditor

I have the following file structure

[image]

And in content.php i have the following JS code

```
        var file = "http://2sense.net/blog/posts/my-second-post.md"
        var opts = {
          basePath: "http://2sense.net/blog/posts/",
          container: 'epiceditor',
          textarea: null,
          basePath: 'epiceditor',
          clientSideStorage: true,
          localStorageName: 'epiceditor',
          useNativeFullscreen: true,
          parser: marked,
          file: {
            name: 'epiceditor',
            defaultContent: '',
            autoSave: 100
          },
          theme: {
            base: '/themes/base/epiceditor.css',
            preview: '/themes/preview/preview-dark.css',
            editor: '/themes/editor/epic-dark.css'
          },
          button: {
            preview: true,
            fullscreen: true
          },
          focusOnLoad: false,
          shortcut: {
            modifier: 18,
            fullscreen: 70,
            preview: 80
          },
          string: {
            togglePreview: 'Toggle Preview Mode',
            toggleEdit: 'Toggle Edit Mode',
            toggleFullscreen: 'Enter Fullscreen'
          }
        }
        window.editor = new EpicEditor(opts);
        editor.load(function () {
          console.log("Editor loaded.")
        });

        $("#openfile").on("click", function() {
            console.log("openfile");
            editor.open(file);
            editor.enterFullscreen();
        })
```

When i try to open the file with "editor.open(file);" does not happen anything. And I have verified that the event is triggered proprely when i press the button.
Do you have any idea how to fix this, or do you have a real example... the documentation for the API on the epiceditor website does not say so much.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client side JS cannot open desktop files (or, not easily or cross browser). This would be a nice feature to use with the File API, but that's not implemented. EpicEditor stores "files" in localStorage. When you do `editor.open('foo')` you're basically doing: `JSON.parse(localStorage['epiceditor'])['foo'].content`. This has been asked a few times, so I made a ticket to make it more clear in the docs.

https://github.com/OscarGodson/EpicEditor/issues/276

Does that help?

P.S. a pull request with docs that make sense to you are always welcome :)

Comment: Thank you Oscar! Any other "known" solution for achieve this?

Comment: Use your backend lang to write to it like `editor.import($filename, $content)` or do it with ajax like `$.get('/path/to/file.md', function (data) { editor.importFile('file', data) })`